# Framework issues in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm running the latest version of Xcode and am try to create an app for IPhone with IAd integrated into it and I have tried to integrate it many ways, but I keep receiving this error every time, ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mini/Desktop/TheDateGetter/iAd.framework/iAd, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) I'm guessing this is a framework issue, because all of the code and everything else it correct. All help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This error only happens when you build for the simulator and you wouldn't have this error if building for a device. I wonder how you got yourself into this situation with iAd, which should have a simulator-compatible binary in its framework?

Answer (score 0):

Check under Build Phases for your target which frameworks are you linking against. You will need to remove then the iAd framework from /Users/mini/Desktop/TheDateGetter and link the correct one from the iOS SDK.
[image: frameworks for your target]

[image: the correct iAd framework]